# C++ handling bad_alloc exception, C2276 error code

Tags: c++, exception, bad-alloc

I have tried to create a program in C++ that can catch and handle bad_alloc exception.

While writing the code, I have noticed no errors but when I have tried to compile this code I got C2276 error code and C3876 in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017.

The error itself seems to appear in the catch{...} code block.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class CanGoWrong {
public: 
    CanGoWrong() {      
        char *pMemory = new char[9999999999];
        delete[] pMemory;
    }
}; 

int main()
{
    try {
        CanGoWrong wrong;
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc &e){
        cout << "Caught exception: "<< e.what << e << endl;
    }

    cout << "Still running" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The error with code C3867 ("non standart syntax, use &") I fixed this way :

from

```
cout << "Caught exception: "<< e.what << e << endl;
```

to:

```
cout << "Caught exception: "<< &e.what << e << endl;
```

Still, the error C2276 won't disappear. I guess there is something to do using basic std::exception class.

I want to understand how to do it right, this code is an course sample that I must follow and understand.

Comment: `what` is a function, you probably wanted to call it like this: `e.what()`

Comment: Thank you for fast response, I tried it. Still not working, unfortunately.

Comment: `<< e <<` won't work either. Neither `std::exception` nor `std::bad_alloc` has overloaded `operator <<`. When I fix these two things, [it works on gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/shS7YhjZTgbyaB1t).

Comment: Is it Error C3876 or C3867?  And what is the message with error C2276?  [Edit] your question to make corrections and add additional information.  Also add the full and correct description for the other error (you have a typo in your summary).

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! Still I removed mainly all of #include headers, saving only <iostream> and <string> library and it worked without all of the rest. Now I am going to figure out which functionalities can add every lib you have included additionaly. Thank you again.

Comment: Include the standard header `<exception>`, catch by `const` reference, call `e.what()`, and don't output `e` itself.    Preferably, don't use `"pch.h"`.    That will get the code to compile.   It won't guarantee that an exception will be thrown, for various reasons.

Comment: "pch.h" is mandatory for my IDE, without it, I am getting an error "unexpected end of the file", thanks for tip, Peter.